# Using npm set config _auth with a GitHub Secret fails

Tags: github-actions, npm-config

The following npm config set, in my "run" section does not work in my GitHub action.

`npm config set //my.registry.io/npm/:_auth {{ secret.NPM_ACCESSTOKEN }}`

I know the value of `secret.NPM_ACCESSTOKEN` is correct, I've been able to verify with an alternative method.

However I need to use the `npm config set _auth value` method instead of using a ".npmrc".

I've tried a variety of methods for example:

```
token=$(echo "$(curl -u "$UsernameKey" $Uri)" | extract_token()
npm config set _auth $token
```

This returns me exactly the same value as the one stored in GH secrets and works successfully. However means I'm making an additional request with the curl.

Comment: How did you verify that value?

Comment: I used the value inside an npmrc file

Comment: Right. Well, your syntax is not correct. Should be `'${{ secrets.NPM_ACCESSTOKEN }}'`.

Comment: That also failed. Does it need to be `//my.registry.io/npm/:_auth` or `//my.registry.io/npm/:_authToken`

Comment: I believe it's `_authToken`.

Answer (score 1):

After double checking all the secrets and passing them into an env (via GitHub) action. The following was the working solution.

Note that I did provide single quotes around the `env.NPM_ACCESSTOKEN` and `_auth` instead `_authToken` worked for me. (thanks @azeem)

```
npm config set //my.jrog.io/npm/:_auth '${{ env.NPM_ACCESSTOKEN }}'
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set email ${{ env.NPM_USERNAME }}@email.com
npm config set registry https://my.jrog.io/npm/npm
```